# Why does my function return an 'empty' array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-calendar-api

I have a `var gehad` that calls a function that takes all events from a google Calendar and pushes them into an array named "test". The test array is then returned to the `var gehad`, But it always returns an array without `length`.

Also inside the loop where I push events into the test Array, I can `console.log(test[0].id)` and it will `return` the id. but if I `console.log` the same thing outside the loop. it returns an `Uncaught TypeError`

I am so confused as to why it does that.

my code:

```
var gehad = listUpcomingEvents();

console.log(gehad); //<!-- output:[0]{kind: "calendar#event, id: "10010", status: "confirmed", …} length:1 __proto__: Array(0)
console.log('gehad.length: ' + gehad.length); //<!-- output: 0; expected output: 1
console.log(gehad[0]);//<!-- output: undefined

function listUpcomingEvents() {
    //Creates a list of all events on the google Calendar
    var test = [];

    gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
        'calendarId': 'primary',
        'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
        'showDeleted': false,
    }).then(function (response) {
        var events = response.result.items;

        if (events.length > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                test.push(events[i]);
                console.log(test[0].id) //<!-- returns a valid id
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(test[0].id) //<!-- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    return test;
}
```

Thank you.

(yes there are events on my google calendar)

Comment: The `gapi` function you're calling is **asynchronous**. That's why you pass a callback to `.then()`.  The callback is invoked when the operation completes, but that will be long after `listUpcomingEvents()` has returned.

Comment: It's because the `list()` call is asynchronous. You need to work with the result data in the `then()` callback.